# How to retrieve Approval Details from Bills and Adjustments using Contract web services

Tags: acumatica

When coding to retrieve Bills and Adjustments info from the Contract based web services (using Postman), I noticed in the Endpoints screen that there are no collection objects for Approval Details.  How do you extend a default endpoint that would include that collection object?  The only ones available are Applications, (Document) Details, and TaxDetails.

Bottom line:  How do I extend an endpoint to add an 'Approval Details' collection object?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps.

1. Select the Default Endpoint and click Extend[image]
2. Set a name and a version (you can copy same from default) [image]
3. Select Bill folder and hit Insert on the top left [image]
4. Add new Detail collection named Approvals [image]
5. Select new Approvals collection and on the 2nd tab on the right click on Populate [image]
6. Select Approvals on the Object Selector and Select the columns you want to expose on the grid. [image]
7. Then you can save and you new approval collection will be available on the extended Endpoint. [image]